# Gauss law and curl

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, coulombs-law

I have seen that Gauss law works mainly because $\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{E}=0$, and that we are implicitly using this when finding the charge enclosed using Gauss law. Why is that? I have seen the derivation, and it solely uses Coulomb law. Is it because the Coulomb law describes an irrotational field and it wouldn't for sure work for another one? Is there a physical interpretation to why a zero curl ensures Gauss law (if it does)?

Comment: Do you know [Faraday's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction)?

Comment: Why do you think Gauss’ Law has anything to do with the curl of the field? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law#Equivalence_of_integral_and_differential_forms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simply not true that $\nabla \times \mathbf{E}=0$  makes Gauss's law work. Gauss's law $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{E}=\rho/\epsilon_0$ is part of the four generically valid Maxwell equations and is valid regardless of whether the curl of the electric field is zero or not.  So you can always find the charge enclosed within a Gaussian surface by taking the surface integral of the electric field on the Gaussian surface.

Moreover, you cannot derive Gauss's law using Coloumb's law because Gauss's law is the more basic law. Rather, you can use Gauss's law to derive Coloumb's law in static situations. You're correct in noticing that the field described by Coloumb's law is an irrotational field. And in static situations, this would be perfectly good because the Faraday law $\nabla \times \mathbf{E} =-\frac{d\mathbf{B}}{dt}$ ensures that the electric field would be irrotational in a static case (so the correct thing to say is that Coloumb's law requires the curl of the electric field to be zero, not Gauss's law).

Finally, there are non-static situations as well where Coloumb's law can be efficetively valid (and can be derived using Gauss's law) if the situation has certain symmetries. Here, by "effective", I mean that that the Coloumb's law wouldn't be valid for individual charged particles who are moving but if they're moving in such a way to cancel each other's non-Coloumbic parts of the electric field, then as an aggregate, their electric field would still be described by Coloumb's law. For example, see Section $18.2$ from [this Feynman lecture](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_18.html).

Comment: *Rather, you can use Gauss's law to derive Coloumb's law in static situations.* If you are assuming electrostatics then technically can't you get to Gauss's law from Coulomb's law.

Comment: @BioPhysicist In electrostatics, the two are equivalent, I agree. But when one says "Gauss's law" it's supposed to mean one of the four Maxwell equations and you can't derive _that_ Gauss's law from Coloumb's law.

Comment: So then what do you call $\nabla\cdot\mathbf E=\rho/\epsilon_0$ in the electrostatic case?

Comment: @BioPhysicist I don't know I'd just say Gauss's law in electrostatic limit? :P I mean do we need different names for general laws in each of the special cases? I don't think so.

Comment: Right, $\nabla\cdot\mathbf E=\rho/\epsilon_0$ is Gauss's law. When we say "Gauss's law" this is what we mean whether it is electrostatics or not.

Answer (score 0):

Faradays observed in experiment that when he was changing magnetic, electric field was generated. $$\vec\nabla\times \vec E=-\frac{\partial \vec B}{\partial t}$$

> changes in magnetic field produces electric field.

What if magnetic field isn't being changed? So if there is magnetic field that will remain constant if there's no magnetic field then RHS automatically becomes $0$, derivative of constant is $0$.

$$\vec\nabla \times \vec E=0$$

> for a constant magnetic field, electric field remains constant.